# Safety of PostgresQL run in Docker container

Tags: docker, postgresql

Postgres is available as a docker image on [dockerhub/postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres). Configuration is easily done via environment variables but they also state

> Warning: the Docker specific variables will only have an effect if you start the container with a data directory that is empty; any pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup.

That makes me wonder if there is a safety risk when having a Dockerfile like this

```
FROM postgres
COPY *.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

and a docker-compose.yml like this

```
    database:
        build:
            context: ./database/
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test123
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        volumes:
            - databasevol:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        networks:
            - net

volumes:
    databasevol:
        driver: local

networks:
    net:
        driver: bridge
```

which will rebuild the current database image based on `postgres:latest` which may lead to the database being initialised by version 12.4 but later being read by version 13.0. The possibility of having the DBMS identify the data directory as corrupted and purging it horrifies me.

Hence the question, is it safe to run databases in docker containers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise against using postgres:latest and instead specify the major version you want (ie. postgres:12).

No respectable DBMS will drop your database when updating the DBMS, however it might refuse to start (as does PostgreSQL).

You can fairly safely (**always have backups nevertheless**) upgrade the cluster when switching major version through any of the methods listed in the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/upgrading.html).

Answer (score 1):

There may be some minor performance issues for DBs run by docker but nothing else is different.

But you should never use "latest" as your image tag in production environment; It's like turning on automating update !